# Using StringTemplate with TableForm

Tags: string-manipulation, output-formatting

I have a table given by

```
Module[
  {l = 10, list = StringTemplate["<* Range[l] *>"][]}, 
  TableForm[Table[{3*x, 4*x}, {x, 0, l}], 
    TableHeadings -> {{list}, {"3 x", "4 x"}}]]
```

The idea is to have a vertical column of incremental values of `x` as the left-hand `TableHeadings`. But instead, I get `list` as a single entry in curly braces:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: why not just  `Module[{l=10},  TableForm[Table[{3*x, 4*x}, {x, 0, l}], 
     TableHeadings -> { Range[0,l], {"3 x", "4 x"}}]]`?

Comment: Simple answer - because I'm a doofus! Thanks @kglr. Could you promote that to answer status, and I'll give it a tick.

Comment: Richard, posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: Ticked. Appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, the original issue is that the `StringTemplate` returns _the string_ `"{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}"` and not _the list_ `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Module[{l = 10}, 
 TableForm[Table[{3*x, 4*x}, {x, 0, l}], 
  TableHeadings -> {Range[0, l], {"3 x", "4 x"}}]]
```

[image]